# Error: "OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started" at GetAuthorizationContextAsync(String returnUrl) (IdentityServer)

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, duende-identity-server

I get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started.` when calling `GetAuthorizationContextAsync(String returnUrl)` which is part of `Duende.IdentityServer.Services.DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService`.

This method is called via `OnInitializedAsync()` method in a razor component which is being used as a login form/page.

I think that `OnInitializedAsync()` is getting called too many times. After spending some time debugging I can see that this function is called three times when navigating to the page. On the third time it throws the error and the connection is dropped. The sequence is as follows:

1. First call of OnInitializedAsync - I assume a pre render, executes okay.
2. Second call of OnInitializedAsync - executes okay. Browser empty but is view is rendered after this function finalizes.
3. Third call, don't know why it is being called as by this point the form has already rendered. The error is thrown and the connection dropped.

Here is my code:

```cs
@page "/Account/login"

@inject IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<EditForm FormName="login-form" Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="UserLogin">
    <InputText Placeholder="Enter your username"
                    @bind-Value=model.Username/>
    <InputText Placeholder="Enter your password"
                    @bind-Value=model.Password/>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</EditForm>


@code {

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    private string? returnUrl { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private LoginInputModel model { get; set; } = new();

    //error thrown on third execution of this method
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);
    }

    private async Task UserLogin() { }

    private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)
    {
        //error thrown
        var context = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);

        return new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

Also, since it is important here is a formatted version of a sample returnUrl.

```
"/connect/authorize/callback?
client_id=webapp&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7188%2Fsignin-oidc&
response_type=code&
scope=openid%20profile%20core-api&
code_challenge=neweRQ7n0ozZYVRUAmkK5Sy9HA_W4zVQZtagNWc_Nx4&
code_challenge_method=S256&
response_mode=form_post&
nonce=638421522594225203.MWZkNTNiNDgtZjNlMS00MTdjLWEwZDItZWQ0ZTRmODkwN2ExM2QzMGIwODgtMjFkYS00ZDk2LTk2NGItOGU2MjE2YzBlNTk0&
state=CfDJ8HEuPZo8hC1NjU6vRJir-D8WZp_uajNVpQxcKBeeTsf0q4Yf8fQykOIXck_1FAo-FKgarNQfBsV9BNoBkICIuTuee89MzYKClkdoUDZcanQs6rRaR6E-EFO8DtPxc6MvZci1bejm2_xV2NSiM9-y9yMrenDSRc6ul3TUgNOjnX4BIwGPfAdSAfO9k0JNVYPwRcCwzCPNJDpLxyR3uQzjqh9_KD6FZ3uRX4hJOtLkJwSakZDdE94wkEh2evubTcvciVEDdhQFnWAp0vL_yEI0qGt8m42urSi6rVHDAemd0zAU8WhCrz-mTLDXvxw-RPiUC6MIutl9HMYrRhwxTuU0kGDBbzcdf4NgJrPEkifmlNAiK2XTSWMGILmoIracKacULA&
x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&
x-client-ver=7.1.2.0"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing. Please post an answer if you make any progress. From what I have figured out, I think it has to do with `@rendermode InteractiveServer`

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51554

Comment: @mxmissile Thanks for the link - In the end I opted to convert my identity project to MVC and it all works perfectly now. I still use Blazor for the rest of my application though. I spent hours trying to find a way to resolve this issue but as that post on GitHub suggests the scenario is not supported yet!

Comment: I actually got it to work in pure Blazor last night, following this article: https://medium.com/@nedy/custom-cookie-authentication-in-blazor-ssr-interactive-server-for-net-8-32fedd33267b

Comment: However all authentication related components cannot use `InteractiveServer`, they have to be SSR.